# Is there any other way to detect global mouse hooks except low level hooks and raw input?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to detect global mouse clicks and move through my Windows desktop app using C#.

I was successful in doing so by using low level mouse hooks. However it unhooks by itself silently and I couldnt rehook it again.

RawInput function is also not applicable.

So, is there any other way for detecting global mouse hooks except lowlevel mouse hook and rawinput function?

```
   private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

   private static Win32Interop.LowLevelHookProc _proc = HookCallback;

    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Install()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        StartRehookTimer();
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(Win32Interop.LowLevelHookProc proc)
    {
        return Win32Interop.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }

    private static void StartRehookTimer()
    {
        Timer _timerClock = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 300000
        };
        _timerClock.Elapsed += OnTimer;
        _timerClock.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool unhookSuccess = false;
        if (_hookID != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // uninstall system-wide hook

            unhookSuccess = Win32Interop.UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

            _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Debug.WriteLine("Unhook: Calling UnhookWindowsHookEx" + unhookSuccess + _hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&
            MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Down-----");
        }

        return Win32Interop.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducable code example, so that someone can assist.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Maybe you did it wrongly. We may be able to help you with *"it unhooks by itself silently"* if you show the code and explain what is happening (why you can't rehook, do you get an exception or what?)

Comment: Added the code which rehooks mouse events in every 5 minutes so that problem of unhooking silently could be neglected. However, the callback function is not called after rehooking although the unhooksucess is true and the pointer returned while resetting hook is not zero.